# MS Project: Loop through filtered tasks

Tags: vba, ms-project

From a MS-Project I'd like to copy to an excel sheet the task names that meet the criteria of a filter. Let's say filter `dumb tasks`.
I was trying something but it's not working:

```
Dim b As Task

For Each b In ActiveProject.TaskFilters("dumb tasks")
    'code to copy to excel
Next
```

Comment: could you specify what is not working ? are you getting an error ?

Comment: yes, it says `object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: So you want to copy all tasks that meets a certain Filter ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: You need to first apply the filter, then loop through the tasks. **Or**, are you using a certain task's field to use this Filter ? like `Duration`, or `Flag1` ?

Comment: after applying the filter how can I loop though the visible tasks? Yes, I use a custom field to create the filter.

Comment: What is the name of the Custom Field ?

Comment: It's `Flag3` and the filter is all the tasks with a `yes` on that field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a custom field `Flag3` for the filter, you can loop through the tasks, and check each one if `b.Flag3 = True`, and then copy this task to Excel.

```
Dim b As Task

For Each b In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If b.Flag3 = True Then
        ' here do your copy>>paste to Excel

    End If
Next
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking as a backup. I'll use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To loop through only the tasks that are visible after applying a filter, select all tasks and loop through the collection of visible tasks.

```
Sub LoopThroughFilteredTasks()

    Dim CurrentTaskUID As Long
    CurrentTaskUID = ActiveCell.Task.UniqueID

    FilterApply "dumb tasks"
    SelectAll
    Dim FilteredTasks As Tasks
    Set FilteredTasks = ActiveSelection.Tasks
    Dim tsk As Task
    For Each tsk In FilteredTasks
        ' do something
    Next tsk
    FilterApply "&All Tasks"

    Application.Find "Unique ID", "equals", CurrentTaskUID

End Sub
```

Note 1: While not necessary, users generally appreciate the active selection being restored at the end of the macro, thus the `CurrentTaskUID` lines.

Note 2: Since filters can be complex, it is preferable to use the actual filter rather than try to replicate it in code.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that you just need to adjust the line

```
Dim b As Task
```

to

```
Dim b As Filter
```

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-taskfilters-property-project) TaskFilters returns a collection of `Filter`s

I hope this solves the issue. If you need more help with your current problem, please ask another question or edit your current one to clarify where you need help.